# Executing an artisan command in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

In Laravel 5.2 when I run any artisan command, for example `php artisan inspire`, it always first run the method "schedule" of class "App\Console\Kernel". Only then will it run the "handle" of command class (in this case, a class of "App\Console\Commands\Inspire").

Can I prevent running "schedule", since in this case I want to just execute a command? After all, to run "schedule" in Laravel 5.2 there is `php artisan schedule:run`, is not it?
Has anyone experienced this?

Sorry for bad english. *translate.google.com*

Comment: Why does it matter that `schedule()` is being run?  Is there an error occurring preventing your code from running?

Comment: Interesting, never noticed this. But apparently no: the method gets triggered by the constructor of Illuminate/foundation/console/Kernel.php which is implemented by App\Console\Kernel. The methods in schedule() don't get triggered though, only scheduled. Is this inconvenient for you?

Comment: It matters to me because in the method of "schedule" of class "App\Console\Kernel" logic implemented concerning only tasks assigned to work on a schedule. But in the example of "inspire" I just want to run the task without running any schedules.  
Therefore, it creates a certain inconvenience for me.